# AWS API Gateway JS SDK get HTTP response code

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using the generated JS SDK by API Gateway. Problem is when theres errors, I get a CORS error and I am unable to get the data inside nor the status code:

[image]

Notice data is "" despite there being a message in the network tab

[image]

My code:

```
AWS.config.region = "ap-northeast-2"
const cognitoParams = {
  IdentityPoolId: "ap-northeast-2:...",
  Logins: {
    "accounts.google.com": googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
  }
}

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(cognitoParams)

AWS.config.credentials.get(function () {

  const api = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    accessKey: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
    secretKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken
  })
  api.ec2Get()
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log('data', data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.error('err', err)
    })
```

Comment: you are sure that AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials is really returning credentials?

Comment: @UXDart yes there's data in access key and secret access key. Or what else should I verify?

Comment: Are you sure you [enabled CORS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html#how-to-cors-console) for your API Gateway resource and deployed your API to stage?

Answer (score 1):

try to pass the region too... so inside:

```
const api = apigClientFactory.newClient({
  accessKey: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
  secretKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
  sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken,
  region: '...'
})
```

because by default it uses 'us-east-1' if you don't pass it

Comment: Hi this solves the problem of having an invalid security token, but I find that when the token expires, I am still unable to get the error message nor status via JS since its a CORS error. Any ideas?

Comment: ok, but the CORS error could be because there is indeed a CORS error, or because the server returned a status different than 200.. what do you see in the console? only the CORS error? if you receive a status 403, then you know the token is expired

Comment: How do I get the HTTP status from the error from SDK generated from API gateway. As you can see from the screenshot, status is 0?

Comment: `.catch(function (err) {
      if(err.status===403) {
    })`

you need to check in the case of an error...

Comment: But the problem is `err.status` is `0` in my case as shown in the screenshot

Comment: can you check the logs in your lambda logs? maybe the error comes from somewhere else... the status code should be 403, in your screenshot it shows the status code of the GET was 403, and same of the options one. I checked the generated sdk for JS for one of a lambda method I have and it doesn't change the status to "0"

Comment: check this https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/566 are you using IE? you seems to be using chrome IMO...

Comment: I am using chrome. I think its a API Gateway authoriser problem. I am able to call API gateway when I am authenticated ... just that when I get some error, its always CORS and I cannot get any info from JS

Comment: use this: `err.response.status` that seems the way to access in axios (the one that uses the generated sdk in JS) when status is different than 200